# How do I flag questions to move them to Chem.SE?

Tags: feature-request, best-practices

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24817/a-quick-method-for-separating-liquids) was asked recently. @dmckee and I both noted that it might work on [chem.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) as well as here. I then stared reading through the physical-chemistry tag, found a few questions, including [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24817/a-quick-method-for-separating-liquids), which were (appropriately) closed as off topic. So I'm wondering, is there a good way to port these over there? I can't find a flag that I can use. Is there a good way to ping the user who asked the question? Is it acceptable for me to simply copy the question and ask it at Chem.SE if I understand it well enough?

Comment: Btw, migration of old questions with votes/etc to beta sites is discouraged. We may not accept a perfectly reasonable chem question for migration if it has too many votes/etc. But no problem in bringing them up for mod consideration :)

Comment: As a note, we can ask for an official migration route (i.e. Chem.SE appearing in close as off-topic menu) when Chem.SE will graduate.

Answer (score 2):

The general way to get a question migrated is to flag for moderator attention or bring it up on meta. Migration is subject to some customary limits

- We won't migrate without approval of the mods on the remove site unless we know that site very well.
- In the case of a beta site we also rarely migrate open questions without the positive say-so of the OP.

Coping a closed question to a better site is not a problem, but migration is better insofar as it leaves a trail of breadcrumbs.

---

In the case of 24817, I'll ask the Chem mods.

One of the Chem mod says

> Just a note, we don't exactly include chemE

but still accepted it for migration. Done.

Comment: Emphasis on "exactly". http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/5131/chemical-engineering-part-of-engineering-and-chemistry. It's more of a per-case basis, this one looks sufficiently chem. (Though I may get some confirmation from the other two mods)  Here's a chemE question that got closed: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/764/how-to-calculate-retention-time-distribution-for-a-cascade-of-arbitrarily-sized

Comment: @Manishearth your first link is broken.

Comment: @emilio deleted post, not much I can do about that :/